# Difference between apt-get dist-upgrade vs dpkg -i *.deb files?

Tags: package-management, software-installation, kernel, patch

I'm about to update meltdown & spectre kernel patches for my Ubuntu machine and one guide says I have to install `*.deb` files with `dpkg` and one says I have to run `apt-get dist-upgrade`.

What's the difference between the two?

Do either of them risk the version bumping from 14.04 to 16.04 for example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a fixed set of Debian packages that you have already downloaded, you use `dpkg --install *.deb`

You use `apt-get dist-upgrade` to download and update all your packages from the repository, intelligently handling disappeared packages. (That is a simplification.) It’s used during distribution upgrades (hence the name). Depending on the contents of your `/etc/apt/sources.list`, this may very well upgrade to 17.10…

Comment: Half of this is false; `apt-get dist-upgrade` does not upgrade to a new distro version (despite the name). To do that you need `do-release-upgrade`

Comment: @zanna -- it does if you change your sources.list to the new version.

Comment: @ravery yeah but that is not a proper way to upgrade and nobody should do that!

Comment: @Zanna – I wonder what `do-release-upgrade` will do after changing your `sources.list` and invoking `apt-get update`.

Comment: @zanna -- It's most useful for someone stuck in a EOL without an upgrade path. It works quite well; though, you will have to manually clean up also.

Comment: @MPi -- I would note to make it clearer that dpkg installs packages you have downloaded. And, dist-upgrade updates installed packages from the repos.

Comment: In any case, there's no reason whatsoever to think OP has done that, so part of this answer is at least very misleading. Upgrading to a new version isn't what dist-upgrade is for or what it normally does

Comment: Good suggestion, @ravery, I added a bit.